# How can I get a pulse in win32 Assembler (specifically nasm)?

Tags: windows, assembly, nasm

I'm planning on making a clock. An actual clock, not something for Windows. However, I would like to be able to write most of the code now. I'll be using a PIC16F628A to drive the clock, and it has a timer I can access (actually, it has 3, in addition to the clock it has built in). Windows, however, does not appear to have this function. Which makes making a clock a bit hard, since I need to know how long it's been so I can update the current time. So I need to know how I can get a pulse (1Hz, 1KHz, doesn't really matter as long as I know how fast it is) in Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many timer objects available in Windows. Probably the easiest to use for your purposes would be the Multimedia Timer, but that's been deprecated. It would still work, but Microsoft recommends using one of the new timer types.

I'd recommend using a [threadpool timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682466%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) if you know your application will be running under Windows Vista, Server 2008, or later. If you have to support Windows XP, use a [Timer Queue timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686796%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

There's a lot to those APIs, but general use is pretty simple. I showed how to use them (in C#) in my article [Using the Windows Timer Queue API](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=817). The code is mostly API calls, so I figure you won't have trouble understanding and converting it.

The [LARGE_INTEGER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383713%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is just an 8-byte block of memory that's split into a high part and a low part. In assembly, you can define it as:

```
MyLargeInt equ $
MyLargeIntLow dd 0
MyLargeIntHigh dd 0
```

If you're looking to learn ASM, just do a Google search for [x86 assembly language tutorial]. That'll get you a whole lot of good information.

Comment: Thanks, you've been quite helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [waitable timer object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687008%28v=vs.85%29).  Since Windows is not a real-time OS, you'll need to make sure you set the period long enough that you won't miss pulses.  A tenth of a second should be safe most of the time.

*Additional:*

The `const LARGE_INTEGER` you need to pass to SetWaitableTimer is easy to implement in NASM, it's just an eight byte constant:

```
period:   dq 100    ; 100ms = ten times a second
```

Pass the address of `period` as the second argument to SetWaitableTimer.

Comment: That looked like it would work, but then I noticed that SetWaitableTimer requires a LARGE_INTEGER, which I have no idea how to create in ASM, especially seeing as it appears to be a C struct. (I'm really pretty new to ASM, I understand the basics but not really anything about how to use it and sadly there isn't anything out there to teach me much) It looks like it would probably be a better idea to write this in C, but when I port it to the PIC ASM would probably be needed, at least inline. Anyway, I think this would probably work if I knew how to apply it :p

Comment: See my edit.  Note that you can mix C and assembler without too much trouble, so if you wanted you could do the Windows-specific parts (which you're going to have to rewrite anyway) in C.